# Remove flickering on actionbar hiding/unhiding

Tags: android, listview

My app has a **listview** and I want to hide the **actionbar** when I scroll down and unhide the actionbar when I scroll up.The problem is not the hiding/unhiding of the action bar but the flickering that is happening due to this.

I googled a lot and the closet thing to a solution I found is this: [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25500353/android-actionbar-hide-show-when-scrolling-list-view)

**According to the solution given:** I have to add a `paddingTop` of **listview** of height equal to actionbar's height, then add a header.

So, I set the padding at the top of the listview with height of `"?android:attr/actionBarSize"` but I am stuck at what to do next. What will be the content of the header.xml file.

**My code:-**

```
             MyAdapter ma = new MyAdapter();
             ListView lv     = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
            lv.setAdapter(ma);

            ma.notifyDataSetChanged();

            //setting onScrollListener on the listview
            lv.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener(){
                private int mLast;
                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view,
                        int scrollState) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(mLast<firstVisibleItem)
                    {
                        if(myactionbar.isShowing())
                        {
                            myactionbar.hide();
                        }
                    }
                    if(mLast>firstVisibleItem)
                    {
                        if(!myactionbar.isShowing())
                        {
                            myactionbar.show();
                        }
                    }
                    mLast=firstVisibleItem;
                }

            });
```

**listview.xml:-**

```
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:divider="@null"
    android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"

    />
```

**onCreate():-**

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
```

All this is doing is adding a permanent padding on top of listview so how will adding a header solve my flickering problem.

Or is there any other way to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: why don't you use `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't knew about it. How can I flickering using this?

Comment: there is no flickering using Toolbar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know why you need header to get rid from flickering. The idea is that when you add

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
```

listview is drawn underneath the ActionBar, thats why its layout doesn't change when actionbar hiding. To prevent content from overlapping by ActionBar when screen is opened you can add [clipToPadding](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/LpAA7q4jw9M) attribute:

```
<ListView
    …
    android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" />
```

**EDITED:**
I get it, you need header to simulate top padding.

Comment: Flickering is removed. But there is one problem, the action bar is now kinda invisible, so when I scroll to the bottom and try to scroll up, the action bar unhides and since it is invisible, the contents are shown inside it.

Comment: You can make it opaque with background color, for example.

Comment: Yeah was just doing that, it works, thanks a lot. But please can you explain how cliptopadding and scrillbarstyle fixed the flickering?

Comment: It's not, flickering was fixed by requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);. cliptopadding needs to prevent overlaping content by action bar.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late reply.

I have faced same problem. But i solved this problem this way:

You should declared your toolbar below of your RecyclerView or ListView and put this line in your RecyclerView or ListView:

```
          "android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"

          android:clipToPadding="false"

         android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay""
```