# ActionBar Flickering while hiding/showing in RecyclerView

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, android-recyclerview

So in my case I am using a RecyclerView to display a list of items but when I try to hide the action bar while scrolling I get this annoying flickering of the screen. I have searched the web for an answer to my problem but so far there has been no luck. So can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

here is my java for hiding the action bar:

```
     @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    this.container = container;
    this.inflater = inflater;
    timePassed = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if(hasMoreResults) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_zone, container, false);

        rootView.findViewById(R.id.imgAdsMap).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(context, AdsMap.class));
            }
        });

        recyclerViewZone = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewZone);
        recyclerViewZone.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);

        // 2. set layoutManger
        manager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);   
        recyclerViewZone.setLayoutManager(manager);
        recyclerViewZone.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        recyclerViewZone.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener()
        {
            int mLastFirstVisibleItem = 0;
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState)
            {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE && !generatedAdsFromScroll)
                {
                    generatedAdsFromScroll = true;
                    runSplitRequest(10);
                }
            }

            //Hiding the Action Bar for better view of the listed items

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                final int currentFirstVisibleItem = manager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                if (currentFirstVisibleItem > this.mLastFirstVisibleItem)
                {

                    ActionBar bar = getActivity().getActionBar();
                    bar.hide();

                    myButton = (RadioGroup)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.radioButtonGroup);
                    myButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else if (currentFirstVisibleItem < this.mLastFirstVisibleItem)
                {
                    ActionBar bar = getActivity().getActionBar();
                    bar.show();
                    myButton = (RadioGroup)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.radioButtonGroup);
                    myButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                this.mLastFirstVisibleItem = currentFirstVisibleItem;
            }
        });

        runSplitRequest(20);
    }
    else
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.error_internet_connection, container, false);

    return rootView;
}
```

This is the XML of the recyclerview:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewZone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imgAdsMap"
    android:src="@drawable/map_button_map_down"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
```

and the style of the action bar:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>

<dimen name="image_detail_height">200dp</dimen>
```

So as you can see I have enabled the action bar to overlay. I have also tried with calling the overlay of the action bar in the activity I call the recyclerview class but the problem remains... no luck the flickering is still there and even if I add padding to the recyclervie XML i just get a black rectangle with the size of the action bar.

Here is the xml of the activity I display the recyclerview:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#353535"/>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioButtonGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
```

z

```
        <RadioButton
            android:button="@null"
            android:checked="true"
            android:contentDescription="ZONA"
            android:background="@drawable/tab_back_selector"
            android:textColor="@color/tab_text_color"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/tabZoneHome"
            android:padding="14dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/home_tab_zone"
            android:gravity="center"/>


        <RadioButton
            android:button="@null"
            android:contentDescription="VISITADAS"
            android:background="@drawable/tab_back_selector"
            android:textColor="@color/tab_text_color"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/tabVisitedHome"
            android:padding="14dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/home_tab_visited"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:checked="false" />

        <RadioButton
            android:button="@null"
            android:contentDescription="SUGERENCIAS"
            android:background="@drawable/tab_back_selector"
            android:textColor="@color/tab_text_color"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/tabSuggestionsHome"
            android:padding="14dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/home_tab_suggestions"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:checked="false" />

    </RadioGroup>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ad_detailholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/quickview_top_gradient"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

</LinearLayout>
<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
```

Comment: It might be nice to have some kind of example project on GitHub to check this out.

Comment: You should look at this thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27616150/remove-flickering-on-actionbar-hiding-unhiding